# How can I remove everything in a string until a character(s) are seen in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-2.7

Say I have a string and I want to remove the rest of the string before or after certain characters are seen

For example, all my strings have 'egg' in them:

```
"have an egg please"
"my eggs are good"
```

I want to get:

```
"egg please"
"eggs are good"
```

and also the same question but how can I delete all but the string in front of the characters?

Answer (score 43):

You can use `str.find` method with a simple indexing :

```
>>> s="have an egg please"
>>> s[s.find('egg'):]
'egg please'
```

Note that `str.find` will returns `-1` if it doesn't find the sub string and will returns the last character of your string.So if you are not sure that always your string is contain the sub string you better to check the value of `str.find` before using it.

```
>>> def slicer(my_str,sub):
...   index=my_str.find(sub)
...   if index !=-1 :
...         return my_str[index:] 
...   else :
...         raise Exception('Sub string not found!')
... 
>>> 
>>> slicer(s,'egg')
'egg please'
>>> slicer(s,'apple')
Sub string not found!
```

Comment: Worth noting -- if the substring is not found, `find` will return `-1` and thus will output the last character of the primary string (eg `e` above). Alternate option is to replace `find` with `index`, which is like `find` but raises `ValueError` if the substring is not found, and then handle the exception accordingly.

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn Indeed, Updated the answer with extra info. tnx for attention.

Comment: Shouldn't it `return` the error message instead of printing it?

Comment: Thankyou for this, this is the method I used and it is working now. the only difference I made was to replace 'Sub string not found!' with pass.

Comment: I used this to get the initial part of the string till the specific string. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

```py
string = 'Stack Overflow'
index = string.find('Over') #stores the index of a substring or char
string[:index] #returns the chars before the seen char or substring
```

Hence, the output will be

```
'Stack '
```

and

```
string[index:]
```

will give

```
'Overflow'
```

Comment: You retain the first part with [:index], while the OP wants to retain everything but. Switching the colon with the index aligns with the question,

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str.join()` and `str.partition()`:

```
''.join('have an egg please'.partition('egg')[1:])
```

Answer (score 2):

use regular expression to fetch the sub string.

```
import re
def slice(str, startWith):
    m = re.search(r'%s.*' % startWith,str) # to match pattern starts with `startWith`
    if not m: return ""#there is no proper pattern, m is None
    else: return m.group(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = "eggs are good"
>>> word = "eggs"
>>> if word in s:
        print s.split(word)[1]
are good
```

Comment: This does not print the splitter parameter egg